# Как с помощью PHP задать статического useragent?

Tags: php

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: Задать где зачем? Непонятно ничего

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = "Default Agent";

var_dump($_SERVER);
```